# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' (in dio package with POST API)

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, dio

```
class AuthenticationApi {
  final dio = Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: FlavorApi.getBaseUrl()));

  Future<dynamic> login(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(
          {'email': email, 'password': password, 'ip': '127.0.0.1'});
      final response = await dio.post(
          '/login?oauth_consumer_key=${FlavorApi.getConsumerKey()}&oauth_consumer_secret=${FlavorApi.getConsumerSecret()}',
          data: formData);
      var responseData = jsonDecode(response.data); //error is coming here
      print('Data = $responseData');
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

}
```

When I convert data into JSON format I am getting the error Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'.

I tried many solutions but it is not fixing can anyone help me why this error is coming with dio package. you can see the issue image below:

[image: Here is the issue image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsonDecode method creates a Map from a String.
Your response.data is already a Map.

You can check the method [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).

Also, I recommend you check JSON Serialization. It is on the same page with the jsonDecode, but here is a specific [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries).

I hope that my answer will help you! :)

Comment: Thank you @Marius
It is working, again thank you for your help.